# Italian from 1600 - what is this letter "p" with a stroke?

Tags: letters, abbreviations

I bought an old book in Italian. It's a collection of letters, published in 1600 in Venezia.

What is this strange letter (and word)? It's the first letter of the second word. It looks like a "p" with a stroke through its descender.

---

Ho comprato un libro antico italiano. È una collezione di lettere, pubblicata nel 1600 a Venezia.

Qual è questa strana lettera, all'inizio della seconda parola? Sembra una "p" con una linea che la attraversa.

[image: Image of text: "più ('p' with a stroke through its descender)-fetto il giudicio;"]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's the word "perfetto" (see [this list of scribal abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Marks_with_relative_meaning)).

Mi sembra che sia la parola "perfetto" (vedi [questo elenco di abbreviazioni scribali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Marks_with_relative_meaning)).